# Cannot change Drush version from 6.1.0 to 7.0

Tags: drush

I am trying to update my version of Drush to include the Omega commands. For this I think I need 7.0. I have run `composer global require drush/drush:7.0.0-alpha5` and this installs the package but when I check `drush version` it still says `Drush Version   :  6.1.0` How do I change my version of Drush to 7.0?

Comment: I found a way to do this using 'brew install --HEAD drush' followed by 'brew switch drush HEAD'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this using `brew install --HEAD drush` followed by `brew switch drush HEAD` The full article where I found this is [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/954766), under **Installing Drush 7.x dev**